# Plugin abandoned by developers. Want to bypass limits on demo

Tags: wordpress, plugins

The plugin is Webay by wemiura. (https://wordpress.org/plugins/get-your-ebay-feedback/)
The demo version limits the number of reviews to 5. I want to bypass the demo limits. I have combed through the php files, but can't seem to find the right code.

Here's the plugin:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7poqn9g9hr404ki/AAC2lwfW7uyNrv-yleWqRzAna?dl=0

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the negative votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's GPL licensed, I don't think I'm violating copyright in posting this.  If someone thinks that's wrong, let me know and I'll remove this answer.

I haven't tested this (I can't be bothered setting up an API ID), but I'd try the following:

Delete this code from `ajax.php` (2 copies) and `cron.php` (1 copy)

```
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix . "wm_get_ebay_fb_table
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM ".$wpdb->prefix . "wm_get_ebay_fb_table
    ORDER BY CommentTime DESC
    LIMIT 5
  ) foo
)");
```

In `widget.php` and `shortcode.php`, delete `if($tmp++ < 5)` (*don't* delete the trailing `{`).  Looking at the code, it shouldn't change the logic to do that.  If I'm wrong, though, and it does break, change it to `if(true)`

I don't know if there are any other changes needed, but I think that'll do what you need.

Comment: Hobo, Thanks! I actually tried that but missed the part in the shortcode and widget.
It works perfectly!

Comment: Cool; happy to help